# How to save file to remote serve with credentials and send a link with the file

Tags: c#, email, server, hyperlink

I am sourcing the data from a store procedure and convert it into an excel file which works fine. Now I want to
save the file in a remote server file (http://IP/Folder/SubFolder/TestFolder/). This server contains credentials to login.

Now I want to do the following,

1. Save the file on remote file server which got credentials
2. Send an email with a download link which will download the file. I don't want create a download function but send
   a link with concatenated with a file.

I know how to send an email but the file is currently not being stored/saved.

```
    public bool DownloadFile(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string emailAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            var company = "CompanyName";
            DataTable dt = GetData(dateFrom.ToShortDateString(), dateTo.ToShortDateString());

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                //creating file name
                var fileName = CsvFilename(dateFrom, dateTo);

                //for testing purpose
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }

                //Writing to the file
                File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());

                string Url = "<a href='http://IP/Folder/SubFolder/TestFolder/" + fileName + "'>Download your file now!</a>";
                
                SetNetworkCredentialsForFileShare(Url, "username", "password");
                
                File.Delete(fileName); //delete from the directory.

                ////Email boy.
                #region Email Body
                StringBuilder emailText = new StringBuilder();
                emailText.AppendLine("Good day,");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("Thank you for downloding your file from <strong>" + dateFrom.ToShortDateString() + "</strong> To <strong>" + dateTo.ToShortDateString() + "</strong> ");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine(" " + Url + " ");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("Please don't hesitate to contact us if there is any discrepancies on the file.");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("Regards,");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine(company);
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("<br/>");
                emailText.AppendLine("This email was sent from an unattended email address!");
                #endregion

                //Send an email to client
                string emailSubject = "File " + fileName + " ";
                SendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Not found!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Network credentials

```
  private void SetNetworkCredentialsForFileShare(string path, string username, string password)
    {
        if (username != null && password != null)
        {
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            CredentialCache netcache = new CredentialCache();
            netcache.Add(path, 445, "Basic", networkCredential);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your first problem is that the file is not stored you should show the code that does that task. Also include any exception details.

Comment: @Crowcoder i think that is what i am missing to store the file in the remote repository. Can you assist with that portion, i have search around and did get something i understand

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help with something as vague and broad as that. There are too many protocols for storing files and providing credentials that I could just be guessing all day.